# How to open a Windows form using VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I need to write a code in Excel VBA to open a windows form written in C#. Assume I have created a form.cs in Visual Studio. Assume namespace where the form is created is ConsoleApplication.

The code is compiled and can be run as a C# project. Assume there are multiple form in this project and hence I cannot just run the .exe that I get after compilation. I want to specifically open form.cs which is a part of this C# project.

Thanks,

Comment: you want to open a windows form with only the code and not even compiled things? another thing is that you also need `form.designer.cs` and all the other resources. Also a windows *form* in namespace *console application*? :D

Comment: Do you want to open compiled application?

Comment: @Ram nope, he IMO wants to open the uncompiled resources to a windows form and then wants to show that freshly compiled one.

Comment: I think I confused you. form.designer.cs also exists. The form is absolutely up and running very well as a C# project. How do I call it from excel using VBA is my question. @cramopy

Comment: @Rama but your actual question is how to open/compile the source code and *not* the compiled `.exe` file. opening the compiled version should be no problem - in this case please edit your question into sth like *how to open a .exe file from vba* (please do not use this word by word!). thanks!